# Blackberry - Find out if spell check suggestions dialog is showed

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, spell-checking

Have you any idea how to find out if spell check suggestions dialog is showed?

I have tried to simple test

```
getScreen().isFocuse()
```

If spell check is called from input field context menu, this works well and returns false.
However if spell check is called by long press of trackball after typing, this code still returns true.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no way of controlling in-line spell checking (besides disabling it at all).
As a workaround, you can start spell checking from code (e.g. before closing a screen):

1. Make sure the field's style has no Field.NON_SPELLCHECKABLE style set.
2. Create spell checking UI: [SpellCheckEngineFactory.createSpellCheckUI()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/spellcheck/SpellCheckEngineFactory.html#createSpellCheckUI()).
3. Pass your implementation of [AbstractSpellCheckUIListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/spellcheck/AbstractSpellCheckUIListener.html) to **SpellCheckUI.addSpellCheckUIListener()**: now you can control spell checking.
4. Run spell checking for the specified field: **SpellCheckUI.spellCheck(field)**.

Voilà!

PS
Spell checking?!! Spell checking!